# Добавление строки в MongoDB

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

В mysql база данных в формате таблиц и для добавления нового столбца используется ALTER TABLE. В MongoDB же, системы таблиц нет, поэтому возник вопрос, как мне добавить новую 4 строчку, каждому пользователю в базе данных?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection.update({},{"$set":{"new":"string"}},{multi:true})
```

Параметр multi обновит все записи, найденные заданному фильтру. В данном примере все записи.
$set - обновит поле если оно есть, в противном случае добавит.